# Minecraft crashes with "java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException" when loading on an older version

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

Whenever I try to run older versions of Vanilla Minecraft it won't allow me to create or load a world in Singleplayer. If I try, it will start to generate the world, then crash.

*Error Message:*

```
---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// Oh - I know what I did wrong!

Time: 2/1/16 10:14 PM
Description: Unexpected error

java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
    at java.nio.Buffer.checkIndex(Buffer.java:540)
    at java.nio.DirectIntBufferU.get(DirectIntBufferU.java:253)
    at bls.a(SourceFile:270)
    at bls.a(SourceFile:220)
    at azd.a(SourceFile:1675)
    at azd.a(SourceFile:1633)
    at biv.a(SourceFile:113)
    at gu.a(SourceFile:70)
    at gu.a(SourceFile:13)
    at ef.a(SourceFile:164)
    at azd.o(SourceFile:1566)
    at azd.ad(SourceFile:753)
    at azd.e(SourceFile:704)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:103)
```

*System Details:*

```
  -- System Details --
Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.7.2
    Operating System: Mac OS X (x86_64) version 10.10.4
    Java Version: 1.8.0_60, Oracle Corporation
    Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
    Memory: 148530064 bytes (141 MB) / 285257728 bytes (272 MB) up to 1048576000 bytes (1000 MB)
    JVM Flags: 5 total; -Xmx1G -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy -Xmn240M
    AABB Pool Size: 18497 (1035832 bytes; 0 MB) allocated, 18497 (1035832 bytes; 0 MB) used
    IntCache: cache: 0, tcache: 0, allocated: 0, tallocated: 0
    Launched Version: 1.7.2
    LWJGL: 2.9.1
    OpenGL: Intel(R) HD Graphics 6000 GL version 2.1 INTEL-10.6.31, Intel
    Is Modded: Probably not. Jar signature remains and client brand is untouched.
    Type: Client (map_client.txt)
    Resource Packs: []
    Current Language: English (US)
    Profiler Position: N/A (disabled)
    Vec3 Pool Size: 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) allocated, 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) used
    Anisotropic Filtering: Off (1)
```

Is this a system problem, is there a problem with my system settings that would cause this error? If so, what steps can be done to correct it. If not, what could be the problem?

Comment: Can you define "older versions"? I see you are trying to run 1.7.2 here, but does this happen for 1.7.X in general? In particular, what about 1.7.4 and higher? Also, what about 1.6.X?

Comment: Try to delegate this profile to custom directory, something like .minecraft/customprofile1.7 , in settings of that profile. This is so important for using Forge, because other versions, vanilla and Forge could collide in files used, so there might be similar problem. Your new versions can collide with this old version, with custom directory you can be sure that this profile cannot use files from other versions.

Comment: It doesn't work for anything lower than 1.7.10, but someone helped me fix it. Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is an issue that occurs when downgrading from Minecraft 1.8 or higher without deleting your `options.txt` file or correcting its `renderDistance` entry. You can fix this by either deleting the file or changing `renderDistance` to 12 or lower. To do this, first open the game directory of the profile as described in this picture ([sourced from here](http://hopper.minecraft.net/help/finding-minecraft-data-folder/)).

[image: Opening the profile's directory]

After that, find the `options.txt` file and either delete it *or* open the file in a text editor and change the line that starts with `renderDistance` to something like `renderDistance:12`. It can be lower, but don't increase it beyond 12. Save the file and launch Minecraft, and it should start.

Sources:

- [MC-38527](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-38527)
- [MC-67266](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-67266)
- [MCX-475141](http://hopper.minecraft.net/crashes/minecraft/MCX-475141/) which contains an almost identical stack trace as well as a link to instructions for deletion.
- [Mojang's help page detailing finding the instance folder](http://hopper.minecraft.net/help/finding-minecraft-data-folder/)